# SPARQL endpoint exception in Jena: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not recognized for SELECT queries

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, dbpedia

It looks like there is a query length or complexity limit on [dbpedia.org/sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). This code fails:

```
        String part = "{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marcus_Garvey__Sound__1>?a?v}";
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT ?a?v WHERE {" + part;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
            query += "UNION " + part;
        }

        query += "}";

        ResultSet resultSet =
            QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query).execSelect();

        while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution qs = resultSet.next();
            qs.varNames().forEachRemaining(name -> System.out.println(name + "\t" + qs.get(name)));
        }
```

with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not recognized for SELECT queries
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:378)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:346)
```

If I change the max `i` value from `14` to `13`, it works fine. If I run the same query using the browser UI, it works fine as well. Any ideas?!

Comment: can you try to set the default graph to `http://dbpedia.org` please?

Comment: also, your syntax is wrong, I don't see why it can work for 13. You need curly braces around the `UNION` parts. The code shown here can't work, not even for i <= 2 - there are also missing spaces between the variables ...

Comment: and yes, for longer queries a `POST` request will be necessary, but again, the current code doesn't work anyways.

Comment: @UninformedUser, thank you for your suggestions! Setting the default graph didn't make a difference. The syntax is not wrong - I have actually tried to run this small program before posting the question. Each `part` already has curly braces. Spaces are not needed either, however, I tried to add spaces everywhere and got the same result. Could you clarify about `POST` request? Would I need to abandon using Jena altogether?